# Unable to add all content to parent div inside a loop

Tags: javascript, for-loop

The array gets console logged fine, but only the last person of the array is inserted in the HTML `<div>`.

Why or what is the failure?

```js
document.getElementById("team").addEventListener("click", show)
function show(){
    document.getElementById("fritz").style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById("bill").style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById("fran").style.display = "block";



    for (i = 0; i < people.length; i++) {

        var persoxn = people[i].printinfos()

        document.getElementById('insert_text').innerHTML = persoxn

        console.log(persoxn)
     }
}
```

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/HigAY.jpg)
[console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KIpbd.png)

Comment: `document.getElementById('insert_text').innerHTML += persoxn`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example

Answer (score 0):

You are overriding (replacing) the `<div>` content in each iteration, therefore all of the elements except the last one get overwritten.

Maybe you meant to use `.insertAdjacentHTML()`:

```js
    for (let i = 0; i < people.length; i++) {
        var person = people[i].printinfos();
        document.getElementById('insert_text').insertAdjacentHTML(person, "beforeend");
        console.log(person);
     }
```

Also *don't forget to declare `i`* inside the loop.